# apex:include vs. Visualforce component, when and why?

Tags: visualforce-component, bestpractice

I recently had a reason to look more closely at the standard [`apex:include`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm) component in Visualforce, and I'm intrigued by the intent behind this component. Would anyone be willing to share some perspectives on when and why it would be more appropriate to use `apex:include` vs. a custom Visualforce component?

It seems to me that Visualforce custom components do the same thing as an apex:include element, and Visualforce custom components have the added benefit of being able to accept custom attributes. The only use case I can imagine right now for using `apex:include` is to bring in a page from a managed package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

apex:include was the original attempt at re-using content between Visualforce pages - its been superseded by components as they are properly re-usable as discrete standalone items.

Doug Chasman, the architect of Visualforce, posted the following on the developer forums in 2008 in response to a question regarding problems with apex:include:

> Why are you using apex:include instead of just creating a custom
>   component? apex:include predates custom components and is only still
>   around for backward compatibility. A custom component has a well
>   defined mechanism for specifying the inputs to the included content
>   via attributes and also has the added advantage of passing objects and
>   expressions instead of just query params/name value pairs...

(You can read the original post [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000094tMIAQ))

One reason you *might* want to use apex:include is that if the main page and the included page use the same controller, they will share the same **instance** of that controller, and can influence each other's behaviour. I wouldn't recommend it though, as it can make the page structure and effects of changing code quite difficult to understand.

As an aside, composition templates are a way to provide a bunch of boilerplate content and functionality across a set of pages, while allowing each page to inject some custom content into certain areas. The poster child use case for this is a web site where each page injects its specific content into the main body, while the header/sidebar etc is provided by the template.

TL;DR - always use components over apex:include

Answer (score 3):

While I don't have a good justification behind this, at DF 2011 tuning VF Pages for Performance, the product managers had a blanket "Don't use apex:include" it has performance issues.

Given that components have a superset of functionality (include doesn't have parameters), I'd suggest just always using components and call it a day.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, @Ralph. Would you happen to have a link to that presentation? I searched YouTube but the only ones that came up seem to be from Dreamforce '13.

Comment: Sorry I don't, but the DF'13 ones would likely be better than the DF'11 since the content would be fresher. The comment I was referring to wasn't in the presentation it was part of the followup Q&A with the crowd, so wouldn't be in the presentation.

Comment: I found a doc about optimizing Visualforce, but it did not mention apex:include.  It did mention avoiding apex:includescript

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great description from Salesforce: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_templates_intro.htm

Comment: Thanks, @snugsfbay. Oddly enough, the same blurb in that page about `apex:include` I think can also be said of [`apex:component`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_comp_cust_def.htm).

Comment: For me, the different tags help provide structure.  So my Template provides a framework and uses composition to know where to insert sections of other pages to provide content and my pages use components for subsections that may access specific sObject data.  I think I only use include for extra CSS or when I have pasted a web-to-lead or web-to-case auto-generated HTML page into a VF page that I include elsewhere (back in the days before field sets).

Comment: Hello, @snugsfbay, I agree with you 100% about using templates, which leverage `apex:insert`, `apex:composition` and `apex:define`. However, I believe `apex:include` is something that's unrelated to templates.

Comment: The doc I linked above is titled "Templating in Visualforce" or something like that and describes using include in templates.  So it is related to templates if you want to use it there in the way they document.

Comment: Here's another Salesforce doc from the "Templating with Visualforce" section of Visualforce online reference which suggests reserving apex:component for code (when a page refers to one sObject type and you need to bring in data from another sObject type, for example): https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_templates_include.htm

Comment: Hello, @snugsfbay, I'm not sure how the page defines "reusable segments of code". Isn't a page being pulled into another page using `apex:include` _also_ a reusable segment of code? Also, (not unique to this documentation page) the documentation leaves doubts in my mind as to its accuracy. If you look at the "displayName" page's sample code, you'll find an `apex:actionSupport` element that is out of place and doing nothing.

Comment: I am not sure a bit of extraneous code that is not even discussed on the page in question renders the entire page false.  You should tweet Bob Buzzard, who wrote an excellent resource for Visualforce dev. and get his input.  You might also want to let SalesforceDocs know when you think there are errors in the documentation.  They love to hear about those so they can make it even better. :)

Comment: Regarding your question about reusable code, I agree that it is vague, which is why I offered an example from my own use.