# Create default Apex:Attributes for custom visualforce component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, custom

I'm building multiple components that have the same attributes and html wrappers and so I was curious about ways to reuse some markup rather than redefining it on every custom component in this series.

For example just as the `Id` and `Render` attributes are default for every component I would like to have some include that makes several other attributes created by default. I was considering [`apex:include`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_include.htm) but I don't believe I can include other components just other VF pages.

I know how to include a component within a component but this is more difficult because I need the attribute declaration to come from a different component like so:

**Parent/Wrapper Component:**

```
<apex:component controller="WrapperController" layout="none">

    <!-- Define DEFAULT Component Attributes -->
    <apex:attribute name="attr1" assignTo="{!a1}" description="" type="String" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="attr2" assignTo="{!a2}" description="" type="String" required="true"/>
    <apex:attribute name="attr3" assignTo="{!a4}" description="" type="String" required="true"/>

    <!-- Define Component -->
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="wrapper-container" layout="block">

        <apex:componentBody />

     </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:component>
```

**Child Component Series**

```
<apex:component controller="ExtendsWrapperController">

    <!-- INCLUDE WRAPPER ATTRIBUTES -->
    <apex:attribute name="custom1" assignTo="c1" description="" type="String" required="true"/>

    <!-- COMPONENT BODY/MARKUP WITHIN THE WRAPPER COMPONENT -->

</apex:component>
```

So first off I need to know is this possible or am I wasting my time? And then if so how should I look about doing this?

**References:**
[apex:include vs. Visualforce component, when and why?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41941/apexinclude-vs-visualforce-component-when-and-why)

Comment: Do you want to be able to use sub components in the `<apex:componentBody />` and have them access attributes defined on the parent/wrapper component?

Comment: Yes, that was part of the original goal I suppose. I couldn't find a way to make this work so I moved on to a a different approach which I outline here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111963/visualforce-components-when-your-controller-extends-an-abstract-class-can-you

Comment: @DanielBallinger For the sake of the question though is that possible? And could you provide an answer to bring some closure to the question?